# Expanding several filenames into one directory in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I want to run awk on several files.  I have the filenames and a path to the files, but I can't seem to connect the two.  Here's what I have tried:

```
files=(a b c)
directory=/my/dir

awk $my_script "$directory/${files[@]}"
```

It awks the first file and leaves the rest alone.  I'd rather not have to add the full path in my array (the values are used in several places).  I think I want brace expansion, but it doesn't seem to work with arrays.  What else could I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using pattern substitution (`#` means something like `^` in regexps): `${files[@]/#/$directory/}`

Comment: It works by invoking the spirit of punctuation-based languages like perl.  You may smell burning feathers.

Comment: Nice! But what you actually want is `${files[@]/#/$directory/}`.

Comment: Ah, yes, I cut and pasted my test without adding that.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in /my/dir/[abc]; do
    awk $my_script "$i"
done
```

Or, if you want to actually just pass all of the file names to awk at once:

```
awk $my_script /my/dir/[abc]
```

If the file names are not actually single letters:

```
awk $my_script /my/dir/{file1,file2,file3,...}
```

Comment: See the section I added with {file1,...}.